# How can I use flag-icon-css with Ionic 4?

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, angular-cli, ionic4

I want to use the https://github.com/lipis/flag-icon-css with ionic-select and https://www.npmjs.com/package/ionic-selectable. I have tried many methods after I installed the packages but it did still does not show me the flag. Can someone please explain to me what I should do for the flags to work

ionic_select.html

```
<ion-select #select1 [(ngModel)]="selectedCode">
<ion-select-option *ngFor="let c of countries" value="{{c.flag}}{{c.code}}">{{c.flag}}{{c.name}}</ion-select-option>
</ion-select>
```

ionic_select.ts

```
countries: any = [
{
  code: '+93',
  name: 'Afghanistan',
  flag: './assets/flags/af.png'
},
```

ionic_selectable.html

```
 <ion-item>
 <ionic-selectable
 item-content
 [(ngModel)]="port"
 [items]="ports"
 itemTextField="country"

 [canSearch]="true"
 (onChange)="portChange($event)"


 </ionic-selectable>
<span class="flag-icon flag-icon-{flag}"></span>
 </ion-item>
```

ionic_selectable.ts

```
class country {
public country: string;
public flag: string;

}
export class Classname {
  ports: country[]; 
  port: country;  
this.ports = [
 constructor(){
  {
    country: 'afghanistan',
    flag: './assets/flags/af.png'
  },
 }
```

Comment: Got exact same problem. Can't figured out so far.